Oracle web logic issue : libiplsn.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have installed oracle web logic 12.1.2.4 in linux server. When i try to access the web link it throws as an error with FRM 93552 cannot connect to run time process.
in forms diagnostic logs it says libiplsn.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Where can find this related package?
I have tried all the ways.

Which JDK are you using to run WebLogic Server instance ?

WebLogic 12c is quite old; make sure it is actually compatible with whatever Linux flavour and version you are running, and that you've met all the prerequisites for installing.

Hey @AlexPoole All the prerequisites are done. We are using SLES 15. do you think that might be causing the issue?

@EmmanuelCollin We are using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.8.20

WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 is supported by Oracle with SLES 15.

Are you running a Fusion Middleware application (ie Forms) on top of WebLogic Server ?

Hey @EmmanuelCollin, Yes we are using oracle forms. weblogic has been installed properly but when we trigger wls_form we get an error as FRM-93552, cannot connect to runtime process.
